# How can simple, low poly stylistic fog lighting be achieved in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, virtual-reality, lighting, light

I'm looking to create an interactable VR world of my low poly scene.

How would I achieve lighting similar to this in Unity?
[image]

I have found [this on the Unity store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/polyquest-worlds-full-pack-vol-1-74631).  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also known as volumetric lighting =) 
You can find countless assets for achieving this, a lot of which are free and of high quality.

The asset you linked is very expensive and if it is what you want to go for then great, but the price is set according to the amount of low poly 3D environments, textures, shaders, prefabs, demo scenes etc... not for the lighting.

If you **only** need volumetric lighting I recommend this free and great asset that will get you set instantly :
[Volumetric Lighting Asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/aura-volumetric-lighting-111664)

It has great documentation but you can always follow this tutorial if you want a little extra visual help to get started :
[YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoN3wZz8bsU)

Otherwise feel free to browse the asset store!

Comment: Note: it is an expensive asset as it is a bundled pack of smaller, cheaper assets, such as [low poly rocks](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/low-poly-rocks-74642), [vistas](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/vistas-74646), and [vertical fog](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/vertical-fog-74647).

Comment: @Draco18s I see... the only reason I would buy the bundle is because it has sample scenes in Unity, and I love the lighting in the asset previews.

Comment: @Alex Each sub-asset has its own sample scenes too.